# How to install lynx on an AWS redhat machine that can't find the package?

Tags: redhat, yum

I'm trying to install lynx on an AWS Redhat machine using the following:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX ~]$ sudo yum install lynx                                    
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7                       | 2.9 kB     00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                         | 3.7 kB     00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common                        | 3.8 kB     00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64/primary_db |  14 MB   00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64/updateinfo | 639 kB   00:00
No package lynx available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

My question is: **How to install lynx on an AWS redhat machine that can't find the package?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the optional channels. On AWS this is done in a different way:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a few choices; each with their pros, cons and sub choices:

- [Add a yum repository](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html) that contains the lynx package, and likely all dependencies needed. [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and [RepoForge](http://repoforge.org/) are most likely candidates here.
- [Find a lynx RPM](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lynx) for your OS version (looks like RHEL7 so the CentOS 7 one will probably be fine). Download and install, chances are this will lead to a search for more RPMs you need.
- Build lynx yourself, requires working build environment and all dependencies:

  - [from src.rpm](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lynx&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=src)
  - [from source](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/)
- Do you really need lynx? There are other text based browsers that are probably part of the RHEL7 package set: w3m and elinks come to mind.

Comment: `elinks` is much better at rendering modern HTML than `lynx`

Answer (score 3):

[As I mentioned in a comment a few years ago...]

`elinks` is much better at rendering modern HTML than `lynx`.  Look at how good frames and tables look:

[image: example of elinks]

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me on RHEL 7.6 in AWS:

```
$ sudo yum install redhat-indexhtml
$ wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/lynx-2.8.8-0.3.dev15.el7.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh lynx-2.8.8-0.3.dev15.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: why the downvote? just curious.